# I am trying to match the wpallimport using the Xpath Filter

Tags: plugins, import, bulk-import

While Matching the Xpath Filter to set not to import properties having the city

Gandia , this works but some properties are having Gandía , Jávea. So it is not matching.

Issue seems to be with this í , á characters.

```
/property[price[1] > 5000 and town[1] != "Jávea" and town[1] != "Calpe" and town[1] != "Elche" and town[1] != "Gandía" and town[1] != "Oliva" and town[1] != "Valencia" and town[1] != "Valle de Albaida"]
```

[image]

Comment: does any body have any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to this issue on documentation of wp all import

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/troubleshooting/encoding/

If you're sure that your XML file is valid, it's not using UTF-8 encoding, and WP All Import is still rejecting it, try adding this code snippet inside your child theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'is_xml_preprocess_enabled', 'wpai_is_xml_preprocess_enabled', 10, 1 );
function wpai_is_xml_preprocess_enabled( $is_enabled ) {
    return false;
}
```